# Drush shell command not finding module

Tags: drush

I am using drush 5.7 and in my command line I can type:

```
drush dl wysiwyg
```

Works great but whenever I create a shell command with several downloads, or even just one download, it throws an error "No release history was found for the requested project"

Very confused and bizarre on why this would be happenning?

Test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#WYSIWYG
#http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg‎
drush dl wysiwyg‎
```

Comment: What folder are you in when you issue that command? Do a pwd first to ensure you're in the right location.

Answer (score 1):

Use cd to go to the right directory, you can later comment it out. If you have multisite, you have sites/default renamed or using multisite you have to go to that directory for the drush to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip making a shell command to get multiple modules and use a drush make file instead.

> What is a makefile?
>
> A makefile is a macro for installing Drupal. It contains a list of
>   files that can be fetched using the power of drush, the command line
>   tool for administering Drupal.
>
> Using this generator you can specify different Drupal core
>   distributions, modules, themes, and external libraries like jQuery or
>   WYSIWYG editors.
>
> The end result is a small text file containing the DNA for a specific
>   Drupal setup — YOUR perfect setup!

*(taken from the What section of [drushmake.me](http://drushmake.me/))*

You can use the service as [drushmake.me](http://drushmake.me/) to generate the make file without having to type it all out yourself if it's relatively simple :)

As an example of what a make file can look like, check [here](https://github.com/Chapabu/MakeFiles).  It's old, and I've not updated it in ages but you'll get the idea.

There's also a pretty concise overview of make files [here](http://projectricochet.com/blog/installing-drupal-using-drush-make).

Comment: I attempted to do that as well but get the same error.  I am wondering if I am not running it from a correct directory or something, but some of the modules work in both drush dl or make file